# Play 2 passing system properties to test cases

Tags: playframework-2.0

When executing 'play test', is there a way to pass in system properties to be used at test cases?

```
String testDB = System.getProperties().getProperty("testDB");

Map<String, String> conf = new HashMap<String, String>();
if (testDB.equals("localdb")) {
    conf.put("db.default.driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    conf.put("db.default.url", "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/db");
} else if (testDB.equals("memorydb")) {
    conf.put("db.default.driver", "org.h2.Driver");
    conf.put("db.default.url", "jdbc:h2:mem:play-test");
} else {
    conf.put("db.default.driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    conf.put("db.default.url", "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/db");
}

running(fakeApplication(conf), new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    int preRowCount = Info.find.findRowCount();
        Info info = new Info("key");
        info.save();
        assertThat(Info.find.findRowCount()).isEqualTo(preRowCount+1);
        info.delete();
    }
});
```

I tried 'play test -DtestDB=localdb', but got null value in testDB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1.2.4

Try `play run -DtestDB=localdb --%test`

I found that at the bottom of http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/ids where it states that `play test` is equivalent to `play run --%test`.

#### 2.0

Try `play -DtestDB=localdb test`

The system property needs to be before the command.

Comment: I am using Play 2. '--%test' is not being recognized by Play 2.

Comment: For server debugging, I can pass system properties in this way.
$ play debug -DtestDB=localdb
$ test

Comment: This isn't working for the activator command, which play 2 is now using