# Pass System Properties in Play Framework Test with Activator

Tags: java, testing, playframework, system-properties

Play framework uses

```
activator test
```

to run all tests.

How do I pass Java System properties to my test cases.
The following won't work

```
activator -Dsettings="/settings/settings.json" test
```

Coincidentally, the above will work if I am using the `~run`command instead.

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923474/play-2-passing-system-properties-to-test-cases) question, but it is only valid for the `play`
command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found a solution (Play 2.3.8)

In build.sbt add something like this:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dsettings=" + Option(System.getProperty("settings")).getOrElse("default.json")
```

then

```
activator -Dsettings="/settings/settings.json" test
```

can override the `settings` key

Disclaimer: I tested this for `testserver.port`, not for `settings`

Comment: Inspiration for this answer came from: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1017